# Big O notation with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, big-o

Considering the following linq methods are the following:

```
// distinct() is O(n)
// toList is O(n)
// OrderBy is O(n log(n))
```

And I were to do this operation on a string:

```
string s = "efgabcddddddaaaaaaaaaaa";
List<char> myList = s.Distinct().OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
```

Is chaining the `Distinct().OrderBy().ToList()` resulting in this function being `O(n^2 log(n))` or `O(n + n log(n))` ? 
And if I were to add another linq method that's O(n), what would it result in?

Comment: I can't answer to the mathematical equivalence. I forgot most of the arithmetic when I left college. I can say, however, that these are indeed executed in their own context.

.Distinct() will run the distinct command on the set. This requires a single pass to all the records while comparing it with a collection of found unique records. It might be a little more than O(n). OrderBy is already expected... But it will be faster on a smaller subset (Distinct). ToList() then takes the set and copies it element-wise to a new datastructure. I would assume it would be accurate to add the time.

Comment: Umm... why is this being flagged as being opinion-based? Nothing in this is opinion based...

Comment: This was wrongfully closed IMO

Answer (score 4):

With Big O Notation, one only needs to concern oneself with the dominant term, which is O(n log(n)).  Adding other O(n) methods would therefore have no effect on the overall complexity of the algorithm.

See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/258511/119367

Comment: This is what we are taught. This is also assuming that the set doesn't contain duplicates. If you were dealing with a million records that can only have a field value of True or False, the sort would be much quicker than the distinct.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more, the size of the set changes between Distinct and OrderBy - This changes the size of n. When consider infinite series, the dominant term is the divergent factor. Distinct intrinsically gives you a finite set in which case you might be able to optimize the behavior by your order of operations.